# Why some ConcurrenctExecustions are not provisioned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

I have a quick question about provisioned concurrency.
Below are the metrics of my lambda version that has provisioned concurrency set up.

I wonder why the ConcurrentExecutions  and ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions  are not overlapping?

I configure the lambda max PD to be 10.  However, only 2 is used as shown in the graph, 8 being idle.

2 is far below 10. My question is why not all ConcurrentExecutions  are ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions

[image]

Comment: What about there metrics `ProvisionedConcurrencySpilloverInvocations` and `ProvisionedConcurrencyInvocations`?

Comment: any insights to share about this? I'm also getting fractional spillover executions in cloudwatch and trying to make sense of it